# $this->getChild("custom_block") loading same instance

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, blocks, product-list

I am trying to execute below code on product listing page.

```
$this->getChild("custom_block")->setData("product", $_prd->getId());
echo $this->getChildHtml("custom_block");
```

But when I am fetch the ID using below code

```
$this->getProduct();
```

in `catalog/custom.phtml`

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="custom/custom" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="catalog/custom.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

I am getting the same id for the all the products, the id of the product which is first in the list.

Comment: Can you please tell me where you writing this code and $_product is instace of $this->getProduct ??

Comment: Sounds like the first value or the whole block output is cached. Does your custom block extend any core block or declare its own `getProduct()` method? Did you add any cache related configuration? It would help if you showed the code of this block class as well.

Comment: Check for this ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584630/magento-using-custom-variables-in-a-layout-file

Comment: @fschmengler Yes, my custom block extend Mage_Core_Block_Template, but cache is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from @fschmengler, I looked in that perspective. 
Changing

```
$this->getChildHtml("custom_block");
```

to

```
$this->getChildHtml("custom_block", false);
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you execute all the `setData()` calls before the blocks are actually rendered. And since it is always the same block instance you'll end up with the last product ID every time you render the block later.

Move this line

```
$this->getChild("custom_block")->setData("product", $_product->getId());
```

immediately before

```
$this->getChildHtml('custom_block');
```

That should solve it.

Comment: It is like the way you have said, I have updated the question. But the issue is still there.